# Which is the best way to filter data from an array with Vue JS?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, vue.js, ecmascript-6

I'm looking for best practices.

I get this product list from my API:

```
[
    {
        "id": 6,
        "name": "Pechuga de pollo",
        "category": "Chicken",
        "existencia": 100
    },
    {
        "id": 7,
        "name": "Pierna de pavo",
        "category": "Chicken",
        "existencia": 100
    },
    {
        "id": 8,
        "name": "Lonja de pescado",
        "category": "Fish",
        "existencia": 200
    },
    {
        "id": 9,
        "name": "Coca Cola",
        "category": "Soda",
        "existencia": 200
    },
    {
        "id": 10,
        "name": "Jugo de naranja",
        "category": "Juice",
        "existencia": 200
    }
]
```

So I need to filter this array of products by the value "Chicken".

I've tried with the filter() method and It works well.

```
this.chickenProducts =productList.filter(product=>product.category=="Chicken")
```

Then I use the v-for directive with the chickenProducts array to fill the select input that only contains chicken products.

Do you know another way to filter data from an array to fill a select input considering a criteria in Vue JS?
I'm practicing with Vue yet.

Comment: Why do you need another way?

Comment: Just wondering if there is another best way.

Comment: There's no such thing as more than one best way

Comment: Where do you store `chickenProducts`? Can you show more of your code? The API call and the select, maybe?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Your way of implementation is a bit strict. What if you would want to change your filtering condition? or have multiple condition in your code?

If I were you, I would create a method which returns an array based on condition passed into it. the I iterate over that result. This is more straightforward and modular in regards of maintenance and extensibility.

Answer (score 0):

computed filter array?
By the way, I remember Vue1 can used filterBy in v-for, but Vue2 removed it.